# What command to use for reversed $\vDash$?

Tags: symbols, logic

I want to use a symbol similar to

```
$\vDash$
```

but reversed (like if it's mirrored against an imaginary vertical line). I cannot find such a symbol anywhere. I have used detexify too but no luck there either.

Do you know what command and package I should use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Constructed symbol

If the font does not provide the symbol, the mirroring can be done with package `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\Dashv}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@Dashv\vDash
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@Dashv}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \vDash B \Dashv C \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remark:

- The stuff with `\mathpalette` ensures that the symbol is properly scaled if it is used in different contexts (as index, in fractions, …).

### Font package `MnSymbol`

If package `MnSymbol` is loaded (it also changes other math symbols), then the symbol is available as `\leftmodels`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
\[ A \leftmodels B \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result MnSymbol]

### Font package `mathabx`

If package `mathabx` is used (also changes other math symbols), then the symbol is called `\Dashv`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[ A \Dashv B \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mathabx]

Comment: +1: wow, I learned something new! `\mathpalette` looks like a nifty little tool. `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Simply use **\Dashv** from **mathabx** package.

You can find almost any symbol in [The comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

[image]

Comment: This is already covered in [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114367/5764)...

Comment: @Werner I didn't see it (maybe because he started his answer with more advanced stuff). At least for those who want a quick answer my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This would be the logicians' way, I think. Note that the project authors made a deliberate decision not to adjust the length of the vertical lines according to context. Horizontal lengths are adjusted depending on what is above and below them, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

\[
  A \sdtstile{}{} B
\]
\[
  A \ndststile{}{} B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Two turnstiles]

The advantage of using `turnstile`, as far as I can see, is that it is extremely flexible and can produce pretty much any turnstile you might want. It also works hard to get the spacing right when something is required above or below the horizontal. (Commands such as `\vDash` don't adjust the spacing and line lengths correctly.)