# Rotated `vDash` symbol from `amssymb`

Tags: symbols, alignment, amssymb

I'm trying to rotate the `\vDash` symbol from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\vDashR}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\ensuremath\vDash}}
\begin{document}

$\Sigma\vDash\vDashR\Gamma$
\end{document}
```

The rotation comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13465/mirror-image-of-the-neg-symbol).

With Detexify, I find no predefined symbol.

> My problem is that the whole thing is not correctly spaced, and if my eyes are correct, the two symbols are not even perfectly aligned.

Comment: How about `\dashv`? (Found it with Detexify)

Comment: Rotated or reflected?

Comment: @egreg: reflected would eliminate the vertical alignment problem, is it possible?

Comment: @albert `dashv` is another symbol, with only a horizontal line

Comment: I indeed  I missed the capital `D` of `\vDash`. Maybe the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/what-command-to-use-for-reversed-vdash gives an answer. One of the answers suggests:
"Simply use \Dashv from mathabx package."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rotating it, reflect it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\vDashR}{\mathrel{\reflectbox{$\vDash$}}}

\begin{document}

$\Sigma\vDash \sigma \vDashR\Gamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Perfect, this eliminate both problems. Is using `$...$` equivalent to `\ensuremath`?

Comment: @PeptideChain There's no reason for using `\ensuremath` in that case. The contents of `\reflectbox` is typeset in text mode, so we need to enter math mode.